# How do I convert Tensorflow variables to Matlab structures?

Tags: python, matlab, data-structures, tensorflow, type-conversion

I am trying to pass the model parameters (W & b) from tensorflow to matlab as a dictionary. But when I convert it to a structure in matlab the fields are still tensor variables and I cant do the desired operations on them. Is there any way to fix that and convert them to double or matrix?

In tensor flow:

```
return {'W': W, 'b': b}
```

In matlab:

```
P = py.myModelOutput(samples,labels)
model.parameters = struct(P)
```

Then when I get a print of the structure in matlab it shows the following:

```
ans = 

W: [1x1 py.tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable]
b: [1x1 py.tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable]
```

Trying to convert the fields to double does not help either:

```
double(model.parameters.W)
```

Error using double
Conversion to double from py.tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable is not possible.

Comment: You have to first convert it to numpy arrays using `session.run`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming in your TensorFlow program you have a `tf.Session` object called `sess`, you should modify your code to return the following:

```
def myModelOutput(...):
   # ...
   sess = tf.Session()
   # ...

   # Convert the `tf.Variable` objects `W` and `b` to NumPy arrays.
   W_val, b_val = sess.run([W, b])

   sess.close()  # Assumes `sess` is local to the function.

   return {'W': W_val, 'b': b_val}
```

Comment: Thanks so mcuh! I'm assuming W.eval() does the same job, or does it have to be run()? I ended up returning W.eval() and b.eval() which turned it into a tuple rather than a dictionary but I'd rather return a dictionary. I'm gonna try this now.

Comment: It's equivalent, but it might be slightly more efficient to pass multiple args to `sess.run()`, because that only invokes the TensorFlow runtime once.